# Accessing Silverlight Controls using jQuery

Tags: javascript, silverlight, media-player

I have a silverlight player which I want to access its Play and Pause button on custom buttonclick event using jQuery.

My Player Code as below:

```
<div id="Player">
<object align="left" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="770px" height="490px" id="SPlayer" style="clear: left;">
<param name="InitParams" value="<% GetInitParams(); %>" />
<param name="source" value="/ClientBin/Player.xap" />
<param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
<param name="background" value="white" />
<param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40624.0" />
<param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
<param name="windowless" value="true" />
<div class="left">
<a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=3.0.40624.0" class="noDecor">
<img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" class="noBorder" />
</a>
</div>
</object>
```

My jquery script is as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#SearchCloseBtn').click(function () {
            $("#SearchPanel").animate({ "left": "1000px" }, "fast");
            if (queryObj["IsLoaded"] === "0") {
                var control = document.getElementById("SPlayer");

                control.content.mediaPlayer.Play();//throws error
            }

        });
        $('#SearchBtn').click(function () {
           // debugger;
            $("#SearchPanel").animate({ "left": "560px" }, "fast");
            if (queryObj["IsLoaded"] === "0") {
                var control = document.getElementById("SPlayer");

                control.content.mediaPlayer.Pause();//throws error
            }

        });
```

Works fine in Mozilla and Chrome but IE throws error at this below two lines

**control.content.mediaPlayer.Play();**

**control.content.mediaPlayer.Pause();**

[image]

If I comment out these above two line IE no more throws error.
How can I resolve this issue in IE?